# How to debug cronjob is not trigger in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, cron

I'm in Ubuntu linux.

I just added this cron-job to run every minutes

```
MAILTO="email@gmail.com"                                                                                                                                                                                    
* * * * *  cd /home/forge/bheng/public/code/scraper/; /usr/bin/python3 main.py
```

If I run this command

```
cd /home/forge/bheng/public/code/scraper/; /usr/bin/python3 main.py
```

It works fine.

I never see it run or get an email.

---

I ran a `mail` command

I got

```
└── mail                                                                                                           
"/var/mail/root": 3 messages 3 new                                                                                 
>N   1 Cron Daemon        Sun Oct 15 06:34  21/930   Cron <root@bheng> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run  
 N   2 long@bheng         Sun Oct 15 14:19  15/649   *** SECURITY information for bheng ***                        
 N   3 long@bheng         Sun Oct 15 14:19  15/649   *** SECURITY information for bheng ***                        
?
```

It seems to have issues, how do I fix it ?

---

Did I forgot something or missing something?

Comment: I find it easier to wrap the commands in a `bash` script and tell `cron` to run the script. Easier control, debugging, `bash` command interpreter rather than `cron`'s.

Comment: to exclude path issues, it is generally recommended to use full paths in cronjobs. I'd start by using `/usr/bin/python3 /home/forge/bheng/public/code/scraper/main.py` instead and see if it works

Comment: I don't see why there should be a `cd`; use `/usr/bin/python3 /home/forge/bheng/public/code/scraper/main.py` instead.

Comment: I trust you checked your gmail spam folder as well, just in case the message went there?

Comment: If you change the line to `* * * * *  cd /home/forge/bheng/public/code/scraper/; /usr/bin/python3 main.py >/tmp/out 2>/tmp/errs`, do you see anything in either of those files in /tmp after waiting for a minute?

Comment: @kyo I personally am unsure what you are trying to achieve. You did not include the function of that script, nor did explain to us its purpose. Thus, I am voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If a cron job fails for some reason, you will get a relevant message through mail. Type 'mail' and check the messages.

Comment: When I type mail, I got this : https://i.imgur.com/NrahSbq.png

Comment: Is that what you mean ? Do I need to install that mail plug in ?

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to mail, consider wrapping your commands into a bash script and then using a log file:

For example, you could create a script /home/forge/scraper.bash with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
cd /home/forge/bheng/public/code/scraper/
/usr/bin/python3 main.py
```

Give the script execute permissions (`chmod +x scraper.bash`), and then set up the cron as follows:

```
* * * * * /home/forge/scraper.bash &>> /home/forge/scraper.log
```

The execution output (and errors) should now be available in the /home/forge/scraper.log file. Note that the output is appended to the log file each time the job is run.

Answer (score 0):

The `MAILTO` setting in a `crontab` file is not generally for Internet email delivery, but rather for local user account delivery, e. g. `root` or `someuser`.

Comment: Am I missing something that why my cron is not running ?

Comment: I think it should work find... as long as email is fully configured on the system. Which it may well not be (it often can't be by default), that'd be a good thing to explain in your answer.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions ?